# Set up JBoss application server on eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, application-server

I am trying to set up the jboss application server in eclipse, but I am facing some problems. I have installed merely jboss tools within eclipse. So, the first part of my question is if jboss tools are alone adequate to set up the server or I need an extra installation.

What I have tried is: *Window-> Show view-> View servers*. Then I click on *"new server wizard"* and a window comes up. I select *JBoss AS 7.1* (from JBoss Community) and I click *"next"*. That is the point I cannot come over, because it is required to fill in the field *Home Directory*. I do not what to specify there and the default error message is: "The home directory does not exist or is missing a required file or folder: modules\org\jboss\as\server\main". Should I download and install JBoss AS and then specify the installation directory? I had the impression that it could be managed only with JBoss Tools installation. 
Till now I have followed the instructions from:

http://www.wi.uni-muenster.de/pi/lehre/ss11/eai/tutorials/tutorial_jboss_setup.html

and

http://www.adichatz.org/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=36

Any other site with completed and illustrative instructions?

Comment: Try this: http://javavirtues.blogspot.com/2013/01/configuring-jboss-server-on-eclipse.html

Answer (score 4):

Q: Should I download and install JBoss AS and then specify the installation directory?

A: Yes :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install JBoss. Maybe this link can help you [Starting JBoss AS from Eclipse with JBoss Tools](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools). At the beginning of the doc, it says "

> In order to use JBoss AS from Eclipse, you must first install JBoss AS
>   for your operating system as described in Installing and starting
>   JBoss AS on Linux, Unix or Mac OS X or Installing and starting JBoss
>   AS on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have Eclipse Indigo (3.7) where I got this issue "modules\org\jboss\as\server\main" but I found a workaround (works only if you have a latest Eclipse version also in your machine).

1. Note the current workspace in Indigo
2. Close Indigo
3. Open Luna (i.e. Eclipse 4.4.1)
4. Give the same workspace
5. Set up the JBoss server
6. Close Luna
7. Open Indigo and you should see the same server available now in
   Indigo as well :)